# cannot use Auth::user() in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm working with laravel 4.2 to make a login page and home page. My login page works, then I want to display the username that of the logged in user. here is my code:

LoginController :

```
public function doLogIn(){
        $rules = array(
            'username'    => 'required|min:3',
            'password' => 'required|min:3'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return 'Wrong Require';
        }
        else{

            $user = array(
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'password' => Input::get('password')
            );

            // $password = Hash::make('password');

            if (Auth::attempt($user)) 
            {
                return Redirect::intended('home');
                //return View::make('home.home');
            }
            else
            {
                return 'Wrong Password';
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my home page  that I want to display the username

Home.blade.php:

```
@section('header')
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ Auth::user() }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sigh Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
@endsection
```

Error happen on `{{ Auth::user() }}`

this is error I get

[image]

I'm sure I override $primaryKey in User Model (I mannually create table in mysql not use laravel )

this is my model but it's not correct because I write some part I remember

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'userid';
    protected $fillable = array('username','password');
    protected $hidden = array('username','password');

    //..... and some method require for each implement class
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us your User model?

Comment: now I'm stay at my office and my code at home so I'll write some part that I remember but not correct 100%

Comment: Try this {{ $currentUser->username }} if it works I will make it answer

Comment: @ChanomFirst any progress OR?

Comment: I try you suggest but still not work So. I will rename column to "id" in my database but I get some error when call field in model  I get " Trying to get property of non-object "

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Comment: if name is field on my table I don't have this field name, So I try field I have 

{{ Auth::user()->username }}

and not work still get same error

Comment: Which are the fields of your user table?

Comment: Thank you for help now I ask my friend he work with Laravel  he suggest me to use Extend Framwork (confide)

Answer (score 0):

why don't use id instead of userid?
Can you desc your users table?

Comment: I don't have reason to use " userid " instead " id "  I create my db on MySql Workbench tools. Now I want to know Can i fix this problem if not I will edit my column name

Comment: can you desc your users table?